# Can I get the L2 cache miss count of each process on the windows platform?

Tags: c#, windows, caching, process

I want to compute the memory bandwidth of each process. Anyone can tell me how can I get the L2 cache miss for each process.

Thanks
Hui

Comment: You need to use a profiler for that.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [screenshot](http://software.intel.com/file/33638) on this [Intel Performance Counter Monitor](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor/) page that shows L2 Cache Misses, though I don't know whether it's available per-process.